# preg_match selecting $, meter?

Tags: php, preg-match

Actually I have this data

```
Price $ 1,600,000 Land Size 16m x 27m
```

I want to get this

```
$1,600,000

16m x 27m
```

I tried this

```
/Land Size(.\d+m.x.\d+m)/

/Price(.\$.\d.\d+,.\d+)/
```

I got the result as I want, but I wonder what is the result if m change to km and $ 1,600,000 change to $1600000 or 1600000$.
Is there any easy way to solve this?
I hope everyone will help me. Thank in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the question mark for characters that will not always be there. However, I would recommend the following regexes:

This will match sizes in meters and kilometers.

```
/Land Size (\d+k?m x \d+k?m)/
```

This will match a dolar sign followed by a combination of decimals and comma's.

```
/Price (\$ [\d,]+)/
```